# My Toshiba laptop restarts again and again

Tags: windows-7, bios, bootloader, toshiba-laptop

Please help on how to fix my Toshiba laptop. After reformatting, all data has installed properly, drivers are perfectly installed and no error. After installing I restarted my laptop as the installation process to be complete but it can't go to Windows directly, on startup it shows "Toshiba" then a blinking "_" then restarting and restarting. When I click <kbd>F8</kbd> it shows some options:

1. WINDOWS 7 SLIC LOADER
2. WINDOWS 7 WITHOUT LOADER
3. WINDOWS 7 SLIC LOADER ALTERNATE METHOD
4. WINDOWS 7 SLIC LOADER FUNCTIONAL IT MAY CRASH

I tried options 1, 3, 4 but nothing happened. When I use option 2 which is without loader it works properly, but then if restarted again, same procedure. I want my laptop to directly boot Windows at startup with no need to press any function key. Please help me on  this.

Comment: What's the laptop model, what OS?

Answer (score 1):

The SLIC loader was a specific OEM installation method to allow for OEM product activation on use, etc.

You don't say whether you used the Toshiba recovery method or not, but I gather from...

> after reformatting all data has installed properly driver's are perfectly installed and no error

and...

> When I use option 3 which is without loader it works properly

(I assume you mean Option 2, not 3)...

... these things tell me that you installed a Fresh copy of Windows 7 instead of the Toshiba recovery or recovering from a backup... which means that your new installation would not use the SLIC loader anymore because it isn't there... which means whenever you attempt to boot with it, the boot fails.

So... the question becomes... how do you change the default action so that you don't try to boot with the SLIC loader.  Try this.  Choose option 2, and boot normally.  Once in Windows 7, open the Control Panel, go to System and Security, and then to System.  Click on the Advanced System Settings on the left.  From the popup window, click the Advanced Tab, and go to the Startup and Recovery settings.  Change which version of Windows 7 is the default.
[image]

That should enable you to always boot properly without having to use that boot menu.

Alternately, you might also be able to set up a new Boot Menu with [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/).

Answer (score 0):

I expect there is an error and your BIOS is set to reboot on error.  Go into the BIOS and look for a setting that controls behavior regarding an error on startup.  If it is set to restart, change it.  See if you get any more information.